# How I can show max and min value in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table]

I have a problem to show maximum value and minimum value from salary column in 1 column

output :

SALARY

24000.00

11000.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mysql version 8 or higher, you can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select salary from
(Select salary,
       Row_number() over (order by salary) as rni,
       Row_number() over (order by salary desc nulls last) as rnd
  From your_table t) t
 Where 1 in (rni, rnd)
```

On mysql version below 8, just use `union` as follows:

```
Select min(salary) as salary from your_table
Union 
Select max(salary) from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [max and min function from MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20MIN()%20and,value%20of%20the%20selected%20column.) you can accomplish what you want. The following query will return the result you expect.

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary) from table_name;
```

Comment: Is it showing min and max in one column? nope

Answer (score 0):

Without doing two lookups, and without sorting twice, you can do unpivot the min and max like this:

```sql
select case when isMax = 0 then mn else mx end
from (
    Select min(salary) as mn, max(salary) as mx
    from your_table
) as t
cross join (select 0 as isMax union all select 1) as v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT (MIN(salary), ' to ', MAX(salary)) from table_name;
```

will show something like

```
11000.00 to 24000.00
```

Consider using `FORMAT(...)` so you can get commas.